# Editing torrc on Orbot

Tags: configuration, orbot, android

I'm trying to set my location permanently by adding `ExitNodes {US}` but this doesn't work in the Orbot app on Android.

As this line has to be added at the end of the `torrc` file, I'm wondering if adding it via the settings in the app is doing that.

Answer (score 0):

On a non-rooted device > Install MiXplorer, browse the Orbot apk file, modify the torrc config, exit and sign the apk then install it.

Answer (score -1):

see https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tor-android

search for torrc and you will find someone who did it by modifying the apk

On May 7th, 2011 Anonymous said:

I figured out how to deploy Orbot with a custom torrc file, without having to rebuild Orbot from source, and without needing a rooted phone:
 1. Download the latest Orbot apk file.
 2. Open/extract the apk (it's really just a zip file with a different file extension) with your favorite zip utility.
 3. Remove the META-INF folder from the apk.
 4. Open the torrc file in the assets/ folder and modify it as you like.
 5. Zip it all back up again.
 6. Sign the .apk file using keytool and jarsigner according to the instructions at this URL: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert
 7. Copy to phone and install.

Works like a charm. Tested by specifying strict exitnodes and am now successfully watching the BBC iPlayer on my phone even though I'm in the UK.

You can't edit the torrc on the fly or without reinstalling Orbot using this method, but you don't need a rooted phone and you don't risk getting your torrc file overwritten by the old "default" one by Orbot.

On May 23rd, 2011 Anonymous said:

I used this hint to set up Orbot using a http(s)proxy.
 It Works !
 Nevertheless there should be an option to to that. Perfect were, if this options would map to SSIDs or BSSIDs so it could change automatically if the device is connected to another network.

Thx for the hint.

Milraun

Comment: First, Orbot lets you select the exit country from the very front of the app, on the bottom right of the screen so this is irrelevant and *ancient* advice. Second, Orbot lets you add custom torrc lines through the settings menu under "Torrc Custom Config" so this advise is not only technically prohibitive and a literal copy and paste of 5 year old comments section content, it's far more complex and potentially dangerous than it needs to be.